# How to redirect to l() function link after login?

Tags: navigation, redirection, emails

I'm having a Simplenews newsletter template with a link guiding newsletter readers to a intranet site with more news.

```
<?php print l('hier.', 'node/' . $build['#node']->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)); ?>
```

My problem now is, that if the user is not logged in, that link only brings him to the login site, where he is then stucked.

What would I have to do or what function would help me to somehow provide a link that redirects the not logged in user to the proper aim after logging in, and which would not affect the already logged in user?

Comment: nit3ch's correct answer putted on the questioned snippet: `<?php print l('hier.', 'user/login', array('query' => array( 'destination' => 'node/' . $build['#node']->nid))); ?>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a additional destination parameter to the function.

```
<?php
print l(t('Title'), 'url', array('query' => array('destination' => 'destination_url')))
?>
```

This will create :

```
<a href="url?destination=destination_url">Title</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: or just to previous page: `print l(t('Title'), 'url', array('query' => drupal_get_destination()));`

Comment: @nit3ech - Is `destination` also making the link automatically `absolute`? Seems to...